# Submit input doesn't work in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, modx

Line of code `$input.submit()` didn't work, I want to send the key to enter on input. In Mozilla Firefox, it works, Google Chrome doesn't work.

I work modx minishop2

```
<div class="number">
     <form method="post" class="ms2_form form-inline" role="form">
           <input type="hidden" name="key" value="[[+key]]" />
           <div class="form-group">
                <span class="minus" id="minus[[+id]]"></span>
                 <input type="text" name="count" value="[[+count]]" max-legth="4" id="count[[+id]]" />

                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="ms2_action" value="cart/change"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i></button>
                    <span class="plus"></span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

jQuery 1.11.1

```
 $('.minus').click(function () {
    var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
    var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
    count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
    $input.val(count);
    $input.change();
    $input.submit();
    return false;
});
$('.plus').click(function () {
    var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
    $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
    $input.change();
    $input.submit();
    return false;
});
```

alert($input); return null in Google Chrome

Comment: <form> can be submitted, <input> cannot.

Comment: input no click key enter, when i want send programmatically enter

Comment: alert($input); return null in Google Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery's `.submit()` [can only be attached to `<form>` elements](https://api.jquery.com/submit/).
It takes all the form information and sends it to the specified `action` attribute, via a HTTP method specified in the `method` attribute.

Like this:

```
<form action="my-url.html" method="POST">
```

Therefore, the proposed code might be:

```
<form action="my-url.html" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
         <span class="minus"></span>
         <input name="count" value="3" max-legth="4" type="text">
         <span class="plus"></span>
    </div>
</form>

$('.plus').click(function () {
    var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
    $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
    $input.change();
    $input.closest('form').submit();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Are there any listeners attached to form's submit event that might be returning false or preventing event's default action?

Comment: alert($input); return null in Google Chrome

Comment: Then please insert the correct selector for your input element. But, just for the sake, IWOMM